# React-datepicker date range

Tags: date-range, react-datepicker, react-typescript

I am using react-typescript for my app. I am using [React-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) package. I want to create one global date range component. So I can reuse it to the different component. I have used React-datepicker's `customInput` for styling and created buttons where it display the time. I followed [this link](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-6) for date range logic. In the calendar date range seems work and this is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FsC3.png). I want to display choosing start date and end date in the `customInput's` button. But as soon as I choose the end date, both buttons display the end date's value. I don't know how to fix it.

**This is date range component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker, { ReactDatePickerProps } from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import moment from "moment";
import { Button } from "components/buttons";

export interface IDatepicker {
  value: {
    start: Date;
    end: Date;
  };
  onBlur?: (i: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onFocus?: (i: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onChange: (i: Date) => void;
  buttonComponent?: JSX.Element;
  withPortal?: boolean;
  showTimeSelect?: boolean;
  dateFormat?: string;
  timeFormat?: string;
}

export default ({
  value,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
  onFocus,
  buttonComponent,
  withPortal = false,
  showTimeSelect = false,
  dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa",
  timeFormat = "HH:mm"
}: IDatepicker) => {

  const handleChange = (date: Date | null) => {
    date && onChange(date);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <DatePicker
        selected={value.start}
        onChange={handleChange}
        showTimeSelect={showTimeSelect}
        selectsStart
        startDate={value.start}
        endDate={value.end}
        customInput={
          <Button>
            {moment(value.start)
              .format("MMMM Do YYYY")
              .toString()}
          </Button>
        }
      />
      <div style={{ color: "black" }}>-</div>
      <DatePicker
        selected={value.end}
        onChange={handleChange}
        showTimeSelect={showTimeSelect}
        selectsEnd
        startDate={value.start}
        endDate={value.end}
        minDate={value.start}
        customInput={
          <Button>
            {moment(value.end)
              .format("MMMM Do YYYY")
              .toString()}
          </Button>
        }
      />
    </div>

  );
};
```

**This is the component i am using the date range component**

```
import React from "react";

import TimeLine from "components/datepicker";


export default () => {
const [state, setState] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div>
      <TimeLine
          value={{ start: state, end: state }}
          onChange={setState}
        />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Every time you set the end date, the start date gets overwritten because you're using the same `handleChange` callback in the start and end date `DatePicker` instances. You need to hold not one but two dates in your state, see @Mahesh 's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single state value for both start and end. I think that's the root cause of your issue.
Instead of using

```
const [state, setState] = useState(new Date());
```

I think you should declare it as

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
```